# What does the C# => operator do? (BESIDES being a lambda operator)

Tags: c#, lambda, operators

I know the C# operator => is a [lambda operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx). But today I came across the operator being used this way:

```
static readonly ResourceDictionary ResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
public static ResourceDictionary MyAppResources => ResourceDictionary;
```

Here it doesn't appear to be functioning as a lambda operator. Can anyone tell me what this operator does when used like that?

Comment: @D-Stanley - can you point me to which question this is a duplicate of?

Comment: Look at the link that was inserted above the question.

Answer (score 5):

`=>` is not really an operator in this context, in the sense that it is not used in an expression. This is the new C# 6 syntax for defining *expression-bodied properties*, an equivalent of

```
public static ResourceDictionary MyAppResources {
    get {
        return ResourceDictionary;
    }
}
```

in the old syntax. You can write expression-bodied methods as well, for example

```
public string ToString() => $"User [{FirstName} {LastName}]";
```

instead of

```
public string ToString() {
    return string.Format("User [{0} {1}]", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Isn't an expression-bodied method be a lambda expression?

Comment: @jbyrd I think all this is is syntactic sugar: the result of compiling expression-bodied methods and properties is always a named method or a getter of a named property, not a lambda.